# Jquery If/else slide

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to make a filter for some blogs. Each blog will get a class with a category. If it matches it will show when a button is clicked. I thought I made some decent code, but it's not working. Can you please look at it and tell me what is wrong?

```
$('#filter').on('click', '.het-begin', function() {
    if ($('.blogpagina').hasClass('het-begin')) {
        $('.blogpagina').filter('.het-begin').slideDown();
    }
    else {
        $('.blogpagina').slideUp();
    }
});
```

If you guys want to see it in action you can look at: http://atmos.beer/blog.html. If you want some more information I can provide it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you please describe a little more about why this is not working, such as what is does do, what it does not do, and what you are expecting it to do.

Comment: This is pure guess, `$('#filter').on('click', '.het-begin', function() {
    $('.het-begin').not(this).slideUp();
    $(this).slideToggle();
});`

Answer (score 0):

When you click the filter you could loop through each .blogpagina and check if it has the class het-begin. So it would look like this:

```
$('#filter').on('click', '.het-begin', function() {
 $('.blogpagina').each(function() {
     if ($(this).hasClass('het-begin')) {
        $(this).slideDown();
     } else {
        $(this).slideUp();
     }
 });
});
```